# Running Jena Adapter on Oracle's 11g JVM

Tags: oracle, jvm, sparql, jena

We are trying to develop java stored procedures within `Oracle 11g r2` using the Jena Adapter. Our main purpose for using java stored procedures with the Jena Adapter is ***to be able to emit `SPARQL 1.1` queries*** which get translated automatically to SQL statements.

We have succeeded in running `Jena 2.6.4` within the Oracle JVM; but with no luck with the Jena Adpater (version `11.2.0.3`) since it was compiled for the JRE `ver. 1.6` (Oracle's JVM is `ver. 1.5`).

My question is: is there any Oracle's 11g JVM compatible Jena Adapter available (old packages maybe)? 
In case there are none, what workaround could there be for using SPARQL 1.1 from within Oracle stored procedures?